# How to unit test an SQL query?

Tags: java, sql, database, unit-testing, junit

I have a class `DBHandler` which takes a query, runs it through the SQL server, checks for errors and returns the result. How can I unit test this class?

**Edit**: I'll try to be more precise:
`DBHandler` is in charge of passing the query to the server. In order to test that it actually does that, throws the correct exceptions, etc., I want to connect it to a mock DB which I will populate. My question is - how to do that? How can I create a mock "server" that handles calls?

Comment: @duffymo this is a plan, I haven't implemented it yet. My question is more precisely - how do I simulate an SQL server to return Queries, etc.?

Comment: Why simulate a SQL Server?  You're testing a DBHandler - send the requests to the real database.  No need to mock such a thing.

Comment: @duffymo first of all, I don't want to contaminate my database. Secondly, I want to know exactly what information exists in the test.

Comment: Contaminate your database?  How does testing do that?

Comment: testing of adding a record to the DB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just pass a SQL query, and compare the returned result to expected result. Simple. JUnit is a unit test framework, you can utilise that.

For sophisticated database unit testing, look at [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Not simple, the expected result will probably depend on the database contents. If you're really taking this path, you should have a development only database and put it in a known state before starting the tests. The problem with this approach is that the tests are going to take a long time for any non trivial problem.

Comment: @stivlo: Usually we don't take a development database, but we have a test database. Yes, running a full DBUnit suite might take a long time, but that is acceptable. Running a couple of tests, during coding, don't take much time.

Comment: Hi Adeel, ok agreed, so it might be a good idea to separate suite(s) that are real unit tests (no db tests), from functional tests (db test included).

Comment: @Stivlo: A very valid idea indeed.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning DBUnit. It can't solve my problem, but I think it can be useful in future projects)

Answer (score 4):

I'd use dependency injection to pass in the database connection or something similar, so that the whole thing can be mocked out in the tests. Then you can write tests where the mock query throws exceptions, returns various errors or valid results. Then your tests are just checking that `DBHandler` performs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to either use an in-memory test database that you create and populate on set-up or make all your tests transactional so they don't alter your test database.

You'll have to worry about the presence of data.

If you're using Spring, they have support for transactional unit tests.

It's not clear what you're asking.  You already know about JUnit.  What do you think you're missing?

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution for a mock db works like this:

- Setup an HSQLDB test server
  independent from your app.
- Populate with test data.
- Use conditional code where you
  connect to your real database, to
  connect to the test server. A
  property in your application can
  control this.
- Test the application