# How to test SQL dynamic queries?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, ibatis

My applications are Spring/iBatis (2.3) based. I usually write a lot of dynamic queries in my sqlMaps and I'd like to test my generated SQL queries to avoid any syntax errors. For more precision, I want to:

1. check the SQL syntax (depending on
   the sql dialect) of all my generated queries
2. check if my queries work correctly
   with the actual database structure

Does already exist a library that gives me the chance to check the SQL syntax (step 1), depending on the sql dialect (I'm actually using Oracle), without a database connection?

Does already exist a sqlMap parser which could help me generating all potential queries, containing all combinations of dynamic parameters?

Basically, I'm thinking about a way to avoid writing one (or more) unit test per query. I'd like to automate this step to be sure that my generated queries are always right. Any other suggestions?

Comment: How similar are your DAOs?  That might be more important for testing than specifics about ibatis.  Got a sample of couple of your DAO interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265884/how-to-unit-test-an-sql-query) and some people suggested using [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/). Maybe you should give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know about DBUnit but I was looking for a way to generate every potential query starting from an ibatis sqlmap. Once I generated the queries, I need to test them (here DBUnit can of course be useful).